# Go from cluster to random forest

Tags: r, clustering, random-forest

I'm working on improving a random forest model.  I've done some clustering of the data using the `pvclust` package in R.  I use ward and euclidean distances.  My question is how do I go from the results of the clustering analysis to a better random forest.  Do I need to run multiple `rf` objects with data split along the edges defined in the clustering results or is it something else.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Most of my work is in R.

Comment: What is the connection between cluster analysis (CA) and RF? What is your goal: finding structure in the data using unsupervised methods, or do you want to construct classes from CA and then compute some measures of variable importance with RF, given the constructed classes?

Comment: A bit of both, probably more the first one.  I found that using different RF's on different chunks of data increases the overall AUC.  I'm basically looking for a more efficient way of finding which chunks of data to carve off for their own RF.

Comment: So, it sounds like you are doing a stratified RF - where you find better performance (predictive) by first clustering the data and then fitting a RF to each cluster, instead of fitting the whole sample at once. I assume you are fitting to the same target variable in each cluster? I also assume you are not including the target variable in the cluster.

Comment: Yeah, I'm excluding the target variable to see what the computer finds on its own.  I'm using pvclust package which creates a dendrogram of the results but I'm a bit uncertain of how to turn those results into a model as the clustering algo normalizes the data to minimize impact of outliers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming my comment above, what you are doing is ok for predictive modeling if it is validated properly. I have seen this done before. You could also add in a nominal variable to the overall RF which represents cluster membership for that observation.

I would really look at what is driving the clustering and see if there is a reason for the performance improvement in RF (maybe it is one variable doing something you are not aware of...)